# How to find deployment failure cause? error: deployment "sample-app" exceeded its progress deadline

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I tried simple example from Gitops book

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: sample-app
spec:
  replicas: 1
  revisionHistoryLimit: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: sample-app
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: sample-app
    spec:
      containers:
      - command:
        - /app/sample-app
        image: gitopsbook/sample-app:latest
        name: sample-app
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

It does not work

```
NAME                         READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE   CONTAINERS   IMAGES                         SELECTOR
deployment.apps/sample-app   0/1     1            0           90m   sample-app   gitopsbook/sample-app:latest   app=sample-app
```

Rollout shows

```
kubectl rollout status deployment sample-app
error: deployment "sample-app" exceeded its progress deadline
```

May be it could not pull the image. What else could go wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it was the image problem.

```
kubectl get events 

14m         Normal    BackOff   pod/sample-app-669c6df788-mbhlx   Back-off pulling image "gitopsbook/sample-app:latest"
```